# Protractor Error In New Tab

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to create a test which starts in one tab and then opens another tab, copies the content of the page, and then goes back to the first tab and pastes the contents of the clipboard into a text field.

The problem I am running into is when it switches to the new tab, it is failing with the following error:

`Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.`

Here is my test code:

```js
fit('Text Card - Copied from another webpage', () => {
        const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions
        listView.newButton.click()
        stories.createStory(storyConfigNewTextCard)
        const textCard: ITextCardParts = {
            title: 'Copy and Paste',
            copyPaste: true,
        }
        // Open a  second tab to yahoo.com
        browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
            (function(a: HTMLAnchorElement) {
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.setAttribute('href', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis')
            a.dispatchEvent((function(e: MouseEvent) {
                e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null)
                return e
            }(document.createEvent('MouseEvents'))))}(document.createElement('a')))
        })
        // Switch to the second tab and copy the page to paste into the text field
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then((handles) => {
            const secondWindowHandle = handles[1]
            const firstWindowHandle = handles[0]
            browser.switchTo().window(secondWindowHandle).then(() => {
                browser.wait(() => {
                    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
                    return EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id('firstHeading')))
                }, 3000, 'Could Not Find the Correct Page')
                $('body').click()
                // Select all web page
                $('body').sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'a'))
                // Copy the web page
                $('body').sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'c'))
            })
            // switch back to first tab
            browser.switchTo().window(firstWindowHandle).then(() => {
                text.createTextCard(textCard)
            })
        })
    })
```

Just wondering how I can make this happen. I did try switching from using `protractor.Key.chord()` to `webdriver.Key.chord()` and got the exact same error.

Comment: I think the problem is that the tab you are switching to is not an Angular page, hence the warning. When I look at you code I see you are already using the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`, but you are using it after you have switched, have you tried setting it before you are switching and revert it back when you switch back?

Comment: @wswebcreation I will give that a shot and let you know.

Comment: @wswebcreation That worked superbly. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, can you upvote my comment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @wswebcreation for this simple solution. I simply needed to move the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` to before my switch.